# Resize div according to background image size

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have a div that loads a background image. The height of this div cannot go beyond 60px but the width can be expanded upto any number depending on the image width.

I want all my images that are getting loaded to have original dimensions without getting blurred. Infact, my div should resize according to the image size but should not go beyond 60px.

Currently, I have this css in place for the div.
Using background-size: contain works really well for images greater that 60px height but when the image is smaller it stretches the image and background-size: auto works well for smaller images but larger images expands out of the div.

```
.div{
  background-image: url("../assets/images/example.gif");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 60px!important;
  width: 500px!important;
}
```

I am looking for some css that will show the original image everytime having the div height intact to 60px

Thanks

Comment: are you using a div instead of an img tag for any particular reason?

Comment: Yes, I have to. No choice on that.

Comment: You can't do that without JS.

Comment: If it is achievable via css then I do not wish to use JS. If no luck then I will have to use JS to do some checks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with luck. Background image cannot set the size of an element. It's the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The `backgroundImage` doesn't size the element. It's not how `backgroundImage` was designed.

The contents of the element or any set attributes do. So what you can do is, via JavaScript, create a `<img>` tag with the same source as the `backgroundImage`. In its `onload` event get the size of the image and set the div's `width` to that value.

Along these lines:

```js
const toResize = document.querySelectorAll('.bg-resize');
[...toResize].forEach(elem => {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = elem.style.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
  img.onload = event => {
    elem.style.width = `${event.path[0].width}px`;
  };
})
```

```css
.bg-resize {
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent no-repeat center /cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-resize" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/150)"></div>
<div class="bg-resize" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/600x60)"></div>
<div class="bg-resize" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300x200)"></div>
```

Notice you don't actually have to append the `<img>` elements. They get loaded once you create them.